# Change number of lines and columns in VT420?

Tags: unix

I have a VT420 that displays 80 columns and 24 lines.  I would like to use it with 132 columns and 48 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press F3.  The terminal will display the Set-Up screen.
2. Arrow down to the Display field.
3. Press enter.  The terminal will display the Display Set-Up screen.
4. Arrow down to 24 Lines/Screen field.
5. Press enter to change setting to 48 lines.
6. Press F3 to exit set-up.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure you have a terminfo entry that supports this.  [tic](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tic) and [infocmp](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?infocmp+1) are your friends.  Secondly, you may need to get hold of [documentation](http://vt100.net/docs/) for the VT420 (if you can't find it you may be able to reverse engineer it from [this](http://web.mit.edu/dosathena/doc/www/parser.html)) and 
[modify the terminfo file](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) as necessary.